# Write CMYK image in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, cmyk

I need to add a CMYK Image (`java.awt.BufferedImage`) to a Pdf-Document with iText.

I'm trying to do it with:

```
com.lowagie.text.Image img = Image.getInstance(BufferedImage, bgColor);
```

This produces an RGB image in the resulting PDF. (and I suppose it's a bug, because it just ignores `ColorModel`). However I could use:

```
com.lowagie.text.Image img = Image.getInstance(byte[] rawData);
```

And it produces a correct CMYK-Image in PDF. But for the second case I need to convert `java.awt.BufferedImage` in `ByteArray`. I cannot do it with `ImageIO.write(ByteArrayOutputStream)`. I also cannot do it with `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder` because I must use `OpenJDK`.

Any ideas how can I achieve the correct behavior to write a CMYK image in PDF using iText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what you're asking is how to convert a `BufferedImage` to a `byte[]` to print to PDF?

```
BufferedImage img; // your image to be printed
String formatName; // name of the image format (see ImageIO docs)
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( img, formatName, baos);
byte[] rawData = baos.toByteArray();
```

You should be able to use that for the CMYK-image as you had in your original post:

```
com.lowagie.text.Image img = Image.getInstance(byte[] rawData);
```

Comment: As i wrote - i must use OpenJDK, not Sun JVM. And there is no JPEG codec in OpenJDK. But this solution works with "TIFF", that's OK for me now.